# Late membership renewal fees

Tags: civimember, contributions

Is there a mechanism to charge users extra when they renew their membership after it has expired, e.g. extra 20% if paid after half year, extra 50% if paid later?

Answer (score 2):

It might be easier to make the memberships expensive and give discounts for "early" payments.
I'm not sure without looking into it, but you may be able to do this with [CiviDiscount](https://civicrm.org/extensions/cividiscount)?

Comment: it feels like a workaround but it's an interesting idea. I'll have a look.

Comment: Cool. Would be good to hear how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps if you use a Price set with a 'late payment fee' field that is set to 'on' but is then hidden/ignored via JS based on the membership status of the member then it could do the required. it would also avoid that extra fee being charged if someone clicks auto-renew etc if you offer it

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I want to avoid JS code. It can be powerful but is hard to maintain in the long run

Comment: then i think an extension will be required